# How can I resolve the disabled Bluetooth on resume/power issue on Lenovo laptops?

Tags: drivers, laptop, lenovo, bluetooth

After you install Ubuntu on a Lenovo laptop the Bluetooth will be disabled after reboot or resume.

The only workaround for this issue is to load factory default from the BIOS but this is not something you want to do each time you reboot Ubuntu on a dual-boot machine.

The problem was reported several times over time on Lenovo support forum but nobody from them bothered to take a look on this. Examples:

- http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-B-and-Z-series/How-to-turn-on-bluetooth-on-ubuntu-08-10/m-p/99839
- http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T400-bluetooth-doesn-t-turn-on-after-wake-up-from-standby-mode/m-p/197984

Comment: Can you enable it again manually? and if so how?

Comment: I can't confirm, on my Lenovo machine bluetooth works flawlessly. And you can always enable bluetooth from indicator applet or from blueman.

Comment: Bluetooth enable in widows?(you have alternate operating system (Windows) ?

Comment: I can't replicate this at all. Maybe try flipping the hardware switch or Fn+F5 (or whatever your key is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Lenovo T410 with Ubuntu 10.10.  I just tested it and my bluetooth starts successfully on a reboot and on resuming from standby.  For reference, here's what my bluetooth adapter is called in the lsusb output:
0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller

Comment: Problem was solved in newer versions of Ubuntu.