# How can I recover Bluetooth on my Lenovo S10-3 laptop?

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo

I have a Lenovo S10-3 laptop. Since approximately two weeks ago, Bluetooth is not working anymore. I don't see any icon or notification in the device manager.

I checked my BIOS settings too, and listed down the devices, but the BIOS doesn’t show any Bluetooth information or notification either. I have no idea what happened to my laptop's Bluetooth.

How can I get my Bluetooth connection back?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting the laptop using the wired connection to the Internet. Install the Bluetooth firmwares that might be missing into your machine and your done.

For more, look at this page [How can I resolve the disabled Bluetooth on resume/power issue on Lenovo laptops?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1758/how-can-i-resolve-the-disabled-bluetooth-on-resume-power-issue-on-lenovo-laptops)

Thanks!